# Bulk insert issue with date from excel into SQL Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to bulk insert these two columns from excel into a temp table ##NBP_Table. However, when I do that I get the following error:

> 'Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date'

Does that mean the date aren't in the format it should be to be inserted into a table?

```
create table ##NBP_Table
(
Applicable_Date date,
NBP_Value numeric(4,4)
)

insert into ##NBP_Table
values (01/04/2014,1.7107),
(02/04/2014,1.6482),
(03/04/2014,1.686),
(04/04/2014,1.6681)
```

Comment: you can cast date as CAST('01/04/2014' AS DATETIME)

Comment: `NUMERIC(4,4)` means: **4** digits in total, thereof **4** digits *after* the decimal point - so you can only store values from `.0000` to `.9999` in this column - is that *really* what you want?? If you want 4 digits before and 4 digits after the decimal point, you need to use `NUMERIC(8,4)` instead

Comment: Yes, you need to cast date.

Answer (score 5):

To get the date insert working, please try this

```
create table ##NBP_Table
(
Applicable_Date date
NBP_Value numeric(5,4)
)

insert into ##NBP_Table
values ('01/04/2014',1.7107)
```

The date needs to be in quotation marks

I have also corrected the numeric data type for you

Comment: Does the number have to be bigger than the decimal? If so what is the reason behind this?

Comment: the first number can be looked at like the total digits that make up the entire number, and the second number can be looked at as the decimal points. So you have 5 digits in total, 4 of which are after the decimal

Answer (score 3):

this date in expression is considered as int so it will be performed / operations,
so please use 'before starting date and ' after ending date.
'01-04-2014'

```js
Create table #NBP_Table
(
Applicable_Date date,
NBP_Value numeric(5,4)
)

insert into #NBP_Table
values ('01-04-2014',1.7107),
('02-04-2014',1.6482),
('03-04-2014',1.686),
('04-04-2014',1.6681)
```

Comment: Its getting the 'Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.' when i ran that, any reason why?

Comment: yes, i have corrected this in my answer, you need to use numeric (5,4) for the data you are passing in

Comment: Does the apply to any numeric or float type where the decimal precision has to be smaller than the actual number before it?

Comment: the comment on my answer should explain this for you

Comment: I couldn't get this to work the way you have done, however managed to copy it without converting issues when I replaced the dates to look '2014-04-01'

Comment: ohk..if after changing to (5,4) if still u get problem, then check your date format in sql.

Comment: here 5 is for total number and 4 is for number after decimal point, so 1 digit is before point, you can change it according your requirement.